# Настроить символы которые будут являтся границами слов (Глобальное поведение в ОС Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, текст, настройка, kde

1. Ситуация:
   Пробельные символы являются очевидными границами слова для системы, однако с другими символами возникают вопросы: "*тире*" разбивает составное-слово на два разных? А "*нижнее_подчеркивание*"?

Например:
При перемещении курсора комбинацией клавиш *Ctrl+'Стрелка вправо/влево'* ***по_такому_составному_слову*** ОС считает это слово одним длинным и курсор проходит его как одно целое, однако, если заменить разделитель, ***например-на-тире***, то "*тире*" уже выступает границей слов, и перемещение происходит по каждому слову отдельно.

Данное поведение является глобальным в операционной системе.

На рабочих ПК(Linux Manjaro с KDE Plasma5 и Windows 10) нижнее подчеркивание("_") является границей слова, на домашнем - нет (Linux Manjaro с KDE Plasma5).

2. Что пробовал:

а) Изучил настройки операционной системы - все мимо;

б) Искал ответ в гугл, при поиске использовал различные фильтры (Например, -ворд -word, чтобы исключить из выдачи результаты про MS Word).

3. Вопрос:
   Как самостоятельно задать в операционной системе, какие символы являются разделителями слов, а какие нет и слово необходимо считать как одно целое?

Comment: А в чем именно Вы это делаете? В терминале?

Comment: в каких именно программах/оболочках это происходит? в readline ЕМНИП слова прибиты к алфавитноцифровым символам гвоздями...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78990/110559

Comment: В терминале свои личные настройки, но по всей ОС в графической оболочке есть какие-то глобальные настройки которые за это отвечают. Интересно разобраться как менять это настройки под свой вкус и цвет глобально для программ. 
Хочется изменить поведение в: PyCharm, Firefox, Qt Designer, Atom, LibreOffice и т.д.